# Looking for a book of scary short stories

Tags: story-identification

This was a book that I read as a little kid in the late-seventies. I believe I purchased it at one of the Scholastic book fairs at school.

One of the stories in the trilogy describes a three story haunted house. The second floor spanned the full length of the house from front to back. It's walls were painted black, and the floor was red.

Does this ring a bell for anyone? Sorry, but I can't remember much beyond what I've described above. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)